# Optimal way to join pieces when the cost of joining two pieces is $|x-y|$

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms

There are $N$ pieces each having size $A_i$. The cost of joining a piece of size $x$ and a piece of size $y$ is $|x-y|$. What is the most optimal way to join all the pieces? Can it be solved using the max-flow algorithm?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I think the solution is to keep the pieces in a balanced tree and then join the minimum two items until finished, but I don't have a proof, because I can find an invariant that shows this is better than joining any two other pieces. I saw this question on StackOverflow, thought about it for a while, couldn't find a proof, and suggested the question get migrated here.

Comment: If you join two pieces and then join the third piece, is the effective size of the first two pieces sum of two joined pieces?

Comment: Can you give an example of a joining procedure together with an analysis of its cost?

Comment: Suppose we have 3 pieces of sizes 1,5,8. Then if we chose the following sequence of joins : - Join 1 and 5. Cost = abs(1-5) = 4. Then join the new piece (1+5) to 8. Cost = (1+5-8) = 2.  So the net cost is 6.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have to join the pieces in a sequence of $(N-1)$ joins to make a connected sequence. I also assume if you join two subsequences then the cost of joining is size difference between the size of the last element of the first subsequence and the size of the first element of the second subsequence.

Sort all the pieces and join them in the order of increasing or decreasing sizes. Total cost will be $\max_i A_i - \min_i A_i$. The time complexity of this algorithm will be $O(N \log N + NT)$ where $O(T)$ is the time complexity of joining two pieces.

Comment: What is the "easy" proof? [1,2,3] can be unified with cost 1 by joining 1 and 2, then 3 and 3, but max - min is 2.

Comment: I think that once two pieces are joined, they are no longer available for future joins, but they produce a piece with a size that is the sum of their sizes. As such, joining the pieces with size 1 and 2 produces a new piece with size 3, allowing the final join to be costless.

Comment: @jbapple, If what you say is true, then I don't think greedy algorithm will work. More likely the problem is NP-complete. Your greedy algorithm does not work for input 3 4 5 6. Minimum is 4, your algorithm gives 6. Minimum is ((3 6) (4 5)).

Comment: What @jbapple said is correct. When you join two pieces a and b, you get a new piece of size a+b. So, if you wish to join it to a piece c, then the cost will be abs(a+b-c).

Comment: Then can you update your question. Most probably the problem would be NP-complete. I don't have proof right now, however.